# How to maximize sum of cosine squared plus sum of sine squarred?

Tags: nonlinear-programming, solver, nonconvex-programming

I want to maximize this function

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N}\cos(2\pi f_1t_k+\phi_k+\alpha\pi(k-1))\right)^2+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sin(2\pi f_1t_k+\phi_k+\alpha\pi(k-1))\right)^2,$$ where the variables are $t_k$ and $\phi_k$ and $f_1$ is given by $f_1=28$ GHz $=28000000000$ and $N=16$ and $\alpha=1$.

I don't know what solver to use. Is this function non-convex? Is it hard to find the optimal values?

I tried to use Juniper and Ipopt in the Julia language but I always got NaN solutions.

Comment: Are there any domain limits on $t_k$ and $\phi_k$?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I forgot that. $\tau_k\in[-1,1]\times10^{-7}$ and $\phi_k\in[-2\pi,2\pi]$.

Comment: Multiplying small numbers by large numbers is asking for trouble.  I recommend instead taking $f_1=28$ and $t_k \in [-1,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Hexaly Optimizer, we can confirm the elegant interpretation and solution given by Rob:

```
function model() {

  PI = 3.141592; 
  N = 16;
  F1 = 28;

  t[k in 1..N] <- float(-1,1);
  phi[k in 1..N] <- float(-2*PI,2*PI); 

  obj <- pow(sum[k in 1..N]( cos(2*PI*F1*t[k] + phi[k] + PI*(k-1) )),2) 
    + pow(sum[k in 1..N]( sin(2*PI*F1*t[k] + phi[k] + PI*(k-1) )),2); 

  maximize obj;
}

function output() {
  for[k in 1..N]
    println("t[" + k + "] = " + t[k].value + " phi[" + k + "] = " + phi[k].value);
}
```

Here is the Hexaly resolution log with a time limit of 10 seconds:

```
> hexaly .\orse.lsp lsTimeLimit=10
Hexaly 12.0.20230721-Win64. All rights reserved.

Model:  expressions = 153, decisions = 32, constraints = 0, objectives = 1
Param:  time limit = 10 sec, no iteration limit

[objective direction ]:     maximize

[  0 sec,       0 itr]:  2.73395e-11
[ optimality gap     ]:      100.00%
[  1 sec,  161011 itr]:          256
[  2 sec,  408305 itr]:          256
[  3 sec,  640000 itr]:          256
[  4 sec,  880000 itr]:          256
[  5 sec, 1126904 itr]:          256
[  6 sec, 1372096 itr]:          256
[  7 sec, 1614615 itr]:          256
[  8 sec, 1849999 itr]:          256
[  9 sec, 2092157 itr]:          256
[ 10 sec, 2092157 itr]:          256
[ optimality gap     ]:       50.00%
[ 10 sec, 2332052 itr]:          256
[ optimality gap     ]:       50.00%

2332052 iterations performed in 10 seconds

Feasible solution:
  obj    =          256
  gap    =       50.00%
  bounds =          512

Run output...
t[1] = 0.21471180063292 phi[1] = 0.0832646843060022
t[2] = 0.156390289371164 phi[2] = 0.918941396765761
t[3] = 0.610083475245977 phi[3] = -0.359099069033989
t[4] = -0.443873802890364 phi[4] = -0.29125479048723
t[5] = 0.99999998607111 phi[5] = 0.158259516856785
t[6] = -0.621006854721066 phi[6] = -0.544312419458254
t[7] = 0.323496907222156 phi[7] = -0.205647025090234
t[8] = 0.485645652482093 phi[8] = -0.458003740637076
t[9] = 0.78707054858743 phi[9] = -0.0803543395208796
t[10] = -0.477971981549317 phi[10] = -0.575572519914052
t[11] = -0.316888915678176 phi[11] = -0.640445164286173
t[12] = 0.411307335221625 phi[12] = 0.0539053761039563
t[13] = 0.542077136903721 phi[13] = -0.961165712317072
t[14] = -0.517353397473377 phi[14] = 0.0695838953447903
t[15] = 0.465791702245212 phi[15] = -0.106703190073651
t[16] = 0.548882822090854 phi[16] = 0.983110478290966
```

**Disclaimer: Hexaly is a commercial mathematical optimization solver.**

Answer (score 6):

Allowing $\phi_k\in[-2\pi,2\pi]$ gives you enough freedom to achieve any angle $\theta_k$ as the common argument of $\cos$ and $\sin$.  A geometric interpretation of your problem is to find a sequence of $16$ unit vectors $(\cos(\theta_k),\sin(\theta_k))$ whose sum is farthest from the origin.  Just take $\theta_k$ constant so the steps are in the same direction, yielding objective value $16^2=256$.